# value is still preserved in asp.net webform page even if disable view state and control state

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

The value is still preserved in asp.net webform page even if I disable the view state and control state. Control's value is still preserved in postback even after I disable `Enableviewstate` as false for that page and disable the control state by overriding `SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium()` as empty.

```
/*value is still preserving in asp.net webform page 
      even if disable view state and control state*/

public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CustomTextBox()
    {

    }
     //this method is ipostbackdatahandler's one
    protected override void LoadControlState(object savedState)
    {

       //doing ntng here means we are not saving anything by this way
    }
    //this method is ipostbackdatahandler's one
    protected override void RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
    {

    }

    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {

        //writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Green");
        writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Padding, "5px");
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);

    }
}
```

How can I resolve this situation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can add to your question by pressing the "`edit`" button just under the question rather than press the comment button. I have done the repair edit for you so that you are more likely to get an answer now the question reads better. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the textbox is held in the form post data so ASP.NET is going to automatically preserve it.

If you want the textbox to come back empty, add code such as this, perhaps during prerender.

```
this.MyTextbox.Text = "";
```

Comment: I am just learning asp.net webforms,to get clarity how it works i tried to disable it.manual we can do...........